# Change radio checked with label

Tags: radio-button

I have this problem with this code it works but if I put label does not work any advice?

This code work;

```
<script>

function seleziona(idradiochk) {    
$("#"+idradiochk).attr('checked',true);

};

</script>


<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='radiochoice2525' value='2525' />
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='radiochoice2524' value='2524' />
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='XXradio-choice-1066' value='XX1066' />
</fieldset>

<a onclick="seleziona('radiochoice2525');"  href="javascript:;">clicca</a>
```

This code does not work

```
<script>

function seleziona(idradiochk) {    
$("#"+idradiochk).attr('checked',true);

};

</script>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='radiochoice2525' value='2525' /><label  for='radiochoice2525'>a</label>
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='radiochoice2524' value='2524' /><label  for='radiochoice2524'>b</label>
<input type='radio' name='radiocam' id='XXradio-choice-1066' value='XX1066' /><label for='XXradio-choice-1066'>c</label>
<input type="radio" name="radiocam" id="radiocam2"  checked="checked" value="0"  /><label for="radiocam2">d</label>
</fieldset>


<a onclick="seleziona('radiochoice2525');"  href="javascript:;">clicca</a>
```

without label work whit label not work... any idea how to solve?

Comment: Can you describe the functionality that you are intending? What does "works" mean here?

Comment: When I click the code should select the radio button with id = radiochoice2525